# Sums of integers are squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How can I find the set of distinct positive integers $\mathbb S=\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i\}$ such that:

1. $a+b$, $b+c$, $a+c$ are squares,
2. $d+e$, $e+f$, $d+f$ are squares,
3. $g+h$, $h+i$, $g+i$ are squares,
4. $a+b+c = d+e+f = g+h+i$ is square?

If there are several solutions then choose with minimal $a+b+c$.

Comment: Do you want the integers to be distinct? Otherwise you can dispense with conditions 2 and 3 and most of 4; if 1 is satisfied and $a+b+c$ is a square, you can take $(a,b,c) = (d,e,f) = (g,h,i)$ and satisfy the other conditions for free.

Comment: @MarkDominus, edited: yes, I want them to be distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A computer search gives $a=97$, $b=192$, $c=2112$; $d=720$, $e=801$, $f=880$; and  $g=376$, $h=465$, $i=1560$.

Comment: a far simpler solution than mine!!

Comment: Well I used the computer instead of thinking, so it was easy!

Comment: This obviously yields the related solution 9700 + 19200 + 211200 = 72000 + 80100 + 88000 = 37600 + 46500 + 15600 = $490^2$.  But curiously, there is another solution with $9700 + a + b = 490^2$, namely $9700 + 165024 + 65376 = 490^2$, and in fact we can do even better for $490^2$; there are at least 8 pairwise distinct solutions:     9700 + 165024 + 65376 = 
    26656 + 161700 + 51744 = 
    19200 + 160576 + 60324 = 
    37600 + 156000 + 46500 = 
    30336 + 121764 + 88000 = 
    55200 + 116196 + 68704 = 
    44736 + 110500 + 84864 = 
    72000 + 88000 + 80100 = $490^2$.

Answer (score 6):

You can find 'triples' a, b, and c
by taking any three square numbers, e.g. ${1, 4, 9}$
and then solving for a, b and c simultaneously, such that:
$a+b = 1, a+c=4, b+c=9$

In this case: $a=-2, b=3, c=6$

This case actually doesn't work because $a = -2$
but nonetheless this gives you a general method. If your chosen three numbers are sufficiently far away from 0 (close to each other), negative numbers shouldn't be a problem. In fact, to avoid negatives, I think we need to choose three squares which satisfy the triangle inequality, that the sum of the two smaller squares is bigger than the largest square.

Now note that $2(a+b+c) = (1+4+9)$
So, then you need to find three sets of squares that sum to the same square number, to give your three sets.
<strike>The big square also has to be even, or you'll get non-integer results.</strike> You also have to ensure that you get integer results :S

The 'minimal (a+b+c)' condition is covered by choosing the smallest square number that has this property, so we can stop when we find one solution.

So, we need the smallest <strike>even</strike> square that can be split into three distinct squares, in three distinct ways, where each way satisfies the triangle inequality!

I was hoping for help from The Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences but it only partially covers that situation, at https://oeis.org/A024803, and not well enough to find a suitable square by hand :(

Answer (score 6):

The equation 
$x^2+y^2+z^2=2w^2$ has infinitely many solutions. For example, one family is

$x=3m^2+2mn-n^2$

$y=3m^2-2mn-n^2$

$z=4mn$

$w=3m^2+n^2$

Answer (score 2):

Partial table of results (sorted by $\sqrt{a+b+c}$) :

$\small
\begin{array} {r|lllllll}
49&[97, 192, 2112] & [376, 465, 1560] & [720, 801, 880]\\
71&[*280, 945, 3816] & [*280, 1320, 3441] & [417, 1792, 2832]\\
79&[312, *1057, 4872] & [616, 2520, 3105] & [*1057, 1752, 3432]\\
85&[336, 1600, 5289] & [*2041, 2184, 3000] & [984, *2041, 4200]\\
87&[344, *680, 6545]& [513, 1008, 6048]& [*1169, 1640, 4760]& [*680, *1169, 5720]\\
91&[360, 3240, 4681]& [1392, 3097, 3792]& [1720, 2505, 4056]\\
95&[561, 2464, 6000]& [744, 1281, 7000]& [2136, 2625, 4264]\\
97&[193, 1488, 7728]& [*1128, 2353, 5928]& [*1128, 3633, 4648]\\
98&[388, 768, 8448]& [1504, 1860, 6240]& [2880, 3204, 3520]\\
103&[808, *2328, 7473] &[1584, 3040, 5985]& [2688, 3553, 4368]& [1393, *2328, 6888]\\
105&[1224, 2376, 7425] &[209, *2000, 8816] &[416, *4625, 5984] &[*824, 3800, 6401]& [1616, *4625, 4784]& [*824, *1025, 9176]&[*1025, *2000, 8000]\\
111&[1296, 5265, 5760]& [1712, 2912, 7697]& [2520, 3105, 6696]\\
113&[225, 3744, 8800]& [448, 1953, 10368]& [1320, 4305, 7144]& [2568, 4488, 5713]& [2769, 4120, 5880]\\
115&[*681, 1344, 11200]& [2200, 4200, 6825]& [*681, 4944, 7600]\\
117&[233, 3488, 9968]& [1145, *3080, 9464]& [*2240, 3689, 7760]& [*3080, 4664, 5945]&[464, *2240, 10985]\\
119&[472, 6417, 7272]& [*2280, 3345, 8536] &[*2280, 4945, 6936]\\
121&[480, 3616, 10545]& [*1185, 1416, 12040]& [*1185, 4440, 9016]\\
123&[2360, 6104, 6665]& [1904, 2585, 10640]& [3465, 4104, 7560]\\
125&[249, 6976, 8400]& [*1225, 5016, 9384]& [4176, 5625, 5824] &[4600, 4809, 6216]&[984, *1225, 13416]\\
127&[504, 4680, 10945]& [1968, 3808, 10353]& [3360, 5104, 7665]\\
129&[512, 7232, 8897]& [1016, 4760, 10865]& [2241, 4320, 10080]\\
131&[1785, 6136, 9240] &[*2032, 5712, 9417]& [3936, 5280, 7945]&[777, *2032, 14352]\\
133&[1048, 6873, 9768]& [2313, 7488, 7888]& [4000, 4464, 9225]\\
135&[*536, 1064, 16625]& [*2600, 5681, 9944]& [*536, *2600, 15089]\\
137&[273, 2128, 16368]& [*1345, 3144, 14280]& [*1345, 5544, 11880]\\
141&[3497, 7112, 9272]& [*281, 560, 19040]& [1656, 7560, 10665]& [2457, 6192, 11232]& [2720, 4505, 12656]& [*281, 8000, 11600]\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: curiously although 49 is a valid solution (listed above by Byron), 71, 79, 85 do not form a set of distinct numbers.

Comment: @Ronald: Thanks for the observation Ronald! I didn't verify unicity in my computer search and found such solutions of interest too. Anyway I'll update my table and try to indicate the duplicate numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I used essentially the same strategy as @ronald: Let $(I, J, K)$ be perfect squares, and then if $I+J+K\over 2$ is also a perfect square, we have found a triple $(a,b,c) = ({I+J-K\over 2}, {J+K-I\over 2}, {K+I-J\over 2})$ that satisfies the conditions.  We accumulate many such $(I,J,K)$ triples and see if the $I+J+K\over 2$ values match.  Often, they do. When we find three or more matching sets, we have solved the problem.

```
# Python 3.6
from collections import defaultdict                                                                                                           

N = 1000                                                                                                                                      
is_twice_square = { s*s*2 for s in range(1, N+1) }                                                                                            

solutions = defaultdict(list)                                                                                                                 

for i in range(N+1):                                                                                                                          
    I = i*i                                                                                                                                   
    for j in range(i+1, N+1):                                                                                                                 
        J = j*j                                                                                                                               
        for k in range(j+1, N+1):                                                                                                             
            K = k*k                                                                                                                           
            if I+J <= K or J+K <= I or K+I <= J:                                                                                              
                continue                                                                                                                      
            if I+J+K in is_twice_square:                                                                                                      
                a, b, c = (I+J-K)//2, (J+K-I)//2, (K+I-J)//2                                                                                  
                z = (I+J+K)//2                                                                                                                
                solutions[z].append((a, b, c))                                                                                                
                if len(solutions[z]) > 2:                                                                                                     
                    for triple in solutions[z]:                                                                                               
                        print(" + ".join(map(str, triple)), "=", z)
```

Solutions are abundant. For example, all of the following add up to $901^2$:

```
1801 + 722400 + 87600
8985 + 488040 + 314776
14352 + 606592 + 190857
17920 + 679305 + 114576
21480 + 440920 + 349401
23257 + 694152 + 94392
25032 + 564792 + 221977
39160 + 515865 + 256776
44425 + 721200 + 46176
49672 + 423672 + 338457
63576 + 682920 + 65305
70480 + 577545 + 163776
70480 + 667401 + 73920
97776 + 601120 + 112905
99465 + 426160 + 286176
99465 + 485760 + 226576
101152 + 494832 + 215817
106201 + 413640 + 291960
107880 + 432345 + 271576
112905 + 519120 + 179776
117912 + 471912 + 221977
134472 + 533017 + 144312
141040 + 492576 + 178185
182952 + 360217 + 268632
192432 + 365577 + 253792
197145 + 403480 + 211176
```

**Addendum**: I should explain how I came up with this strategy so that it doesn't seem like I pulled it out of nowhere.  I first tinkered around with various sums and products of $a+b$, $a+c$, and $b+c$ looking for something that seemed promising. All three of these sums are squares, and if you add them all together, you get $2a+2b+2c$, which must be twice a square.  So I knew I was looking for three squares that added up to twice a fourth square, and searching over squares is faster than searching over integers.  So I let $(I, J, K) = (a+b, a+c, b+c)$ and did the search on $(I, J, K)$ instead of on $(a,b,c)$.  I think there's some general principle at work here about looking for lost wallets under lampposts but I'm not quite sure what it is.

Comment: That's what I did too.